# How to Keep element absolute at their location bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some problem with position element can not keep absolute position in resize window (in responsive)
after resposive absolute element shift the ratio parent
How i can keep it ?

In bootplay my code (if resized absolute element to the right) :

[Bootplay](http://www.bootply.com/RvF7uU7Tjb)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 right-section">
          right
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="image"></div>
              <div class="type">Element</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="image"></div>
              <div class="type">Element</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="image"></div>
              <div class="type">Element</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="image"></div>
              <div class="type">Element</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.right-section {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #9EC7E3;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.type {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the absolutely positioned `<div class="type">Element</div>` elements are positioned relative to the column divs, not the `<div class="image"></div>` circles.

If you move the absolutely positioned element inside the circle image divs, and then make those `position: relative;`, you should get what you're after:

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="image">
        <div class="type">Element</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #9EC7E3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
```